# Need to match exact string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression to match a certain portion of this html code:

```
        <TR class="">
                <TD align=left>WebContainer : 312</TD>
                <TD align=left>hung</TD>
                <TD align=left>2014-06-13</TD>
                <TD align=right>08:20:14</TD>
                <TD align=right>-</TD>
                <TD align=right>01:57:46</TD>
        </TR>
```

And I need to match the exact **bold** string starting with the hyphen and ending at the `</TD>` tag.

Also, The 24hr clock in the bottom line needs `01` for the hour portion. I can figure out the clock portion as `\d{1}1:\d{2}:\d{2}` but as for grabbing the whole string including the newline I'm stuck. Please help?

Comment: You may find this Q&A informative (although it's not an exact duplicate so I'm not closing). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

This one select all text between wildcards in the \2 buffer

```
(\*\*)([^\1]+)\1
```

For a better comprehension, [you can see this RE in regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%28%5C%2a%5C%2a%29%28%5B%5E%5C1%5D%2B%29%5C1) ;-)

You can use [this one](http://www.regexper.com/#-%28%3C%5C%2FTD%3E%29%28%5B%5E%5C1%5D%2a%29%5C1) to extract all from hyphen to the next `</TD>` you'll find.

```
-(</TD>)([^\1]+)\1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the question asking how to match the newline, try

```
-</TD>\n.*<TD
```

Answer (score 0):

Just match the bold text:

`/(?!(.*<\/TD){3})-<\/T.*\/TD>/s`

Ensure hour is `01`:

`/(?!(.*<\/TD){3})-<\/T.*01[0-9:]{6}<\/TD>/s`

Where the `s` modifier is `dot matches newline`

Tested here: http://regex101.com/r/sZ6qU5